# Access VBA: What is the difference between dao.recordset vs recordset?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access VBA is there a difference between:

```
Dim rs   As Recordset
Dim rs   As DAO.Recordset
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the references you have set in the VBA project.

If you haven't changed anything, then there are only DAO recordsets. If there is no chance that ADO will ever be used in that project,

```
Dim rs As Recordset
```

is enough to specify a `DAO.Recordset`. But for clarity it is still recommended to use

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
```

But if you have both the Access database engine, and ActiveX Data Objects libraries in your references (see on the right),

[image: DAO and ADO]

then you **must** use the qualifier to specify what recordset you want (see left). If you just use `Dim rs As Recordset` here, it will depend on the order of the references, which one is used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer what I understand is if I just have a DAO connection and don't have the ActiveX Data Object libary referenced then I don't need to call out DAO. If I think in the future I will add the ActiveX libary or add an ADO connection then I should be more specfic.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, that also ADO has a Recordset. Using DAO makes it clear what the object is.